# How to execute a python script after clicking a button in HTML (Django)?

Tags: python, django

I want to execute a python script after a user (registered user) clicks on a button in HTML using Django. How can this be achieved? Can someone give me a hint on how to create the logic in the views.py along with the Html code in the template? Before executing the button code, I want to check whether if the user.id exists in the model. If not, the button doesn't do anything.

Currently, this is basic understanding:

views.py:

```
def button(request):
    #python script 
    return render(request, 'users/home.html')
```

home.html:

```
{% if user.id %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="location.href={% url 'button' %}"> Manual Index </button>
```

FYI, I am new to Django and am still exploring its potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your function in urls.py, example code is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import button

urlpatterns = [
    .....
    path("button/", button, name="button_call"),
    .....
]
```

and simply you can link your button for the url, example code is

```
{% if user.id %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="location.href={% url 'button_call' %}"> Manual Index </button>
```

more flexible way to do this is

```
<a href="{% if user.id %}{% url "button_call" %}{% else %}#{% endif %}"><button class="btn btn-outline-info"> Manual Index </button></a>
```

happy coding

Comment: Yes you can use Ajax! this is your or client preferences, but when you setting your function to a url, the url work in everywhere in same way like ajax, javascript or in templates